# Typescript won't recognize prop values on Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following Vue component.  It's meant to construct a generic side bar that is used two or three times with different data

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <h5>{{ title }}</h5>
        <div v-for="prop of data" :key="prop.id">
            <router-link :to="path(prop.id)">{{ prop.name }}
            <i class="material-icons right">edit</i></router-link>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
    props: {
        data: Array,
        title: String,
        pathbase: String
    },
    methods: {
        path(id): string {
            return `${this.$props.pathbase}/${id}`;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The question I have is this.  Why do I have to use `this.$props.pathbase` to access the `pathbase` value here?  Why is `this.pathbase` considered "invalid" by Typescript?  This isn't the first time where I've tried to access a prop without `$props` but it is the first time Typescript complained about it.  Furthermore, if I use `this.pathbase`, Typescript complains in my editor (VSCode) but Vue compiles without error the project and the component displays and behaves appropriately.

The message on VSCode says: `Property 'pathbase' does not exist on type 'Vue'.`

I want to know why its causing this error because I'd like to understand typescript better.  Why would `this.pathbase` be causing typescript to complain even if it's not a compilation error?  Why am I required to use `$props`?

Answer (score 8):

Normally, you wouldn't need to use `$props`. The issue is similar to a [known Vue/TypeScript issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6841), where TypeScript inference for all `props` is lost when a `prop` has type `{}`. The difference here is you have a `prop` with type `Array` (i.e., `data: Array`) that is causing the same problem, preventing access to `this.pathbase`.

The workaround is to declare the `Array` type with `as () => Foo[]` (or `as PropType<Foo[]>` for version 2.6 or later), where `Foo` is the expected type of each `data` item:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

export default new Vue.extend({
  props: {
    data: Array as () => string[],
  }
})
```

OR:

```js
// PropType added in version 2.6
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue'

export default new Vue.extend({
  props: {
    data: Array as PropType<string[]>,
  }
})
```

[image: screencast demo]

---

**UPDATE** *This was [fixed](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/6856) in Vue [2.6.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v2.6.0).*

Answer (score 0):

Props are read-only, it means the child is not the owner of that particular data and hence it cannot change anything on that data. Pathbase is a property in your props, and to access the property you need to call your props with 'this.props'.